# Как получить путь к файлу?

Tags: android, файлы

Подгружаю изображения списком с помощью `universalImageLoader`. 
Для подгрузки передаю классу `ItemAdapter` список урлов на изображения. 
Изображению кэшируются в каталог на sd-карте `StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(Context.this)`
Непонятно как генерируетя имена закэшированных изображений, лежащих в этом каталоге
Можно ли как-то получить путь по `URL` к определенному изображению?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел вот такой вот метод:

```
File image = DiscCacheUtil.findInCache(imageUri, imageLoader.getDiscCache());
```

Работает на ура.